# Problem to open photo library with Image Tap Recognizer

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am trying to learn swift.
I'm making a photo album app. I wanted to write a code to go to the photo album when the photo I specified is clicked, but nothing happens when I click on the photo. Where am I doing wrong?

```
import UIKit

class DetailsVC: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var artistText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var yearText: UITextField!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        
        //Recognizers
        let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hideKeyboard))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
        
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let imageTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(selectImage))
    }
    
    @objc func selectImage() {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        imageView.image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func hideKeyboard(){
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
    
    @IBAction func saveButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    }
    
    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the gesture recognizer to the image view...

```
imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
let imageTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(selectImage))

// add this line
imageView.addGestureRecognizer(imageTapRecognizer)
```

Comment: What a basic fail, shame for me. Thanks a lot!